# “non-numeric argument to binary operator” when using ggsurvplot() + geom_dl()

Tags: r, survival, direct-labels, survminer

I would like to attach labels using `geom_dl` to a Kaplan–Meier (KM) plot produced by `ggsurvplot`. It works fine if I use the plot part of `ggsurvplot`.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(directlabels)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ disease, data = kidney)
surv_km <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE)
surv_km$plot + geom_dl(aes(label = gsub('disease=','',strata)), 
                       method = list(dl.trans(x = x + .2), "last.points"))
```

However, I get an error If I use the complete `surv_km`

```
surv_km + geom_dl(aes(label = gsub('disease=','',strata)), 
                  method = list(dl.trans(x = x + .2), "last.points"))
```

> ```
> >Error in surv_km + geom_dl(aes(label = gsub("disease=", "", strata)),  : 
>   non-numeric argument to binary operator
> In addition: Warning message:
> Incompatible methods ("+.ggsurv", "+.gg") for "+"
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%++%` instead of `+`. See `?add_ggsurvplot` for more details.

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ disease, data = kidney)
surv_km <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE, legend = "none")
surv_km %++% geom_dl(aes(label = gsub('disease=','',strata)), 
                     method = list(dl.trans(x = x + .2), "last.points"))
```

[image]

To remove labels at the end of the table, we can assign `surv_km[["table"]][["layers"]][[2]]` to `NULL`, e.g.

```
surv_km <- surv_km %++% 
               geom_dl(aes(label = gsub('disease=','',strata)), 
                       method = list(dl.trans(x = x + .2), "last.points"))
surv_km[["table"]][["layers"]][[2]]<-NULL
```

Finally to remove `disease=` in graph's and/or table's legend labels, use `gsub` with `names(fit$strata)`, as so

```
attr(fit$strata, "names") = gsub("disease=","",attr(fit$strata, "names"))
#then repeat above steps
```